# Loop through posts, get year published, remove duplicate years

Tags: php, wordpress

Is is possible to loop through a load of posts, grab the year the post was published then output the years removing any duplicates?

e.g If I have 10 posts, 5 published in 2013, 3 published in 2012 and 2 published in 2011 it will output:

- 2013
- 2012
- 2011

---

I've tried the following but it removes duplicates completely, I just want to show one of the duplicates:

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'policies' );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
    $input = array(get_the_time('Y'));
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata(); 

$result = array_unique($input);
echo $result[0]; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select year as distinct from the table inside the for loop as shown in below code:

```
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $sqlstr=mysql_query("select distinct FROM_UNIXTIME(add_time, '%Y') from tablename");
    $resulty=mysql_fetch_row($sqlstr);
    echo $resulty[0];
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to adjust what I've added to my question?